# Python int and input

Tags: python, input, int

I was wondering how you could make it so that input accepts numbers and letters.

I tried

```
int(input("blah blah blah")
```

but that doesn't work for letters and it accepts only numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you put everything within an int() it forces whatever the input is to be an integer. That is why you don't seem to getting any letters. Try removing the int()

for python 3.x

```
inputFromUser = input("blah blah blah")
```

or

for python 2.x

```
inputFromUser = raw_input("blah blah blah")
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! Also, what is the difference between raw_input and input if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: raw_input() has been renamed to input() in Python 3.x

Comment: and input() in 2.x is the same as eval(raw_input())

Answer (score 2):

You can use exceptions to attempt the int conversion, and otherwise treat the input as a string:

```
my_input = input("blah blah blah")
try:
    int_input = int(my_input)
except ValueError:
    do_something_with_a_string(my_input)
else:
    do_something_with_an_int(int_input)
```

Answer (score 0):

## another problem with that is that you havnt put two brackets at the end of int stuf....

```
int(input("blah blah blah"))
```